# In PHP, how do you scrape a DOMDocument for a certain text pattern, then get the parent element of that matching text's text node?

Tags: php, xml, parsing, simplexml, domdocument

I've built a simple web scraping utility with PHP and cURL, and have been using code like this to grab certain elements of the scraped page by ID, or by Tag Name where no ID is present on the desired element:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($response);
$table = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table')->item(4);
$response = $dom->saveXML($table);
```

Now I've run into a dilemma where I need to go one step further and find the parent element of a certain string or regex pattern of text, because the the site from which I need to collect data doesn't any IDs or classes in the HTML elements I need to extract data from, and various pages may have data organized in different ways, so I can't always rely on the data being in table #X. The only sure-fire way to get the data I'm after off this site is to look for it by its text format, which is always going to be a numeric list starting with "1. " They don't use ordered lists either, or it would be much simpler. It's just a simple table cell with numeric lines separated by a simple `<br>`.

So I was thinking, if I could find the "1. " then it's parent element would be the table cell `<td>` which, after finding it, then I would need to extract its content and perhaps the content of any other adjacent table cells in that table row. There are no other instances of "1. " that I could find in the page or the HTML code, so this approach seems reasonable, if not a bit hacky, but I digress.

So, what's the best way to approach something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always try an XPath query like the following (assuming the content you're after is always in a table cell)

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$cells = $xpath->query('//table/tr/td[contains(.,"1. ")]');
if ($cells->length > 0) {
    // get first item
    $cell = $cells->item(0);
    echo $cell->nodeValue; // text content only
    echo $dom->saveXML($cell); // <td>1. ... </td>
}
```

Comment: Would I then feed $cells to $dom->saveXml($cells) to get their HTML content like I do with the $dom->getElementById() approach? Also, sometimes there's no data on a page. How would XPath respond to those instances?

Comment: @purefusion `DOMXPath::query()` returns a `DOMNodeList`. You'd have to loop over each node in the list and save them separately. If no match is found, the list will be empty. I suggest you read the [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) for more information.

Comment: Ah, I see. It's coming up empty for all responses though, even pages with results. I've tried with and without `$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;` but if I just echo out the raw scraped page, I see the data, so I know it's getting the data properly.

Comment: @purefusion I just did a quick test and it's probably a whitespace issue. Even when setting `preserveWhitespace` to `false`, I still couldn't get a match with `starts-with()`. Changing the query to use `contains()` did work. I've edited my answer accordingly

Comment: I tried that too, but also came up empty. Of course, I was just trying a simple print_r() to expose $cells. Is there a better approach?

Comment: @purefusion `DOMNodeList` is a wily beast and won't expose much via a `print_r`. Check `$cells->length` and given a positive result, `$cells->item(0)`

Comment: We're getting closer. However, when there is a response with 1 or more results, it chokes if I do `echo $cells->item(0)` but I don't get any errors, even though I have errors set to be displayed. Odd.

Comment: @purefusion You can't just `echo` a `DOMNode`. Use `$cells->item(0)->nodeValue` for the text content (does not include any other markup)

Comment: wait, was I supposed to feed that back to $dom->saveXml() to get the markup?

Comment: @purefusion Yes, if you run `$data = $dom->saveXML($cells->item(0));` then `$data` will contain the table cell (`<td>`) and contents.

Comment: Very nice. That worked a treat. Also, it seems the text-only version may be perfect on its own after all. I see you've updated the answer to reflect both approaches. Anyway, the DOM/XML docs on the PHP site have always confused me, so thanks for spelling it all out! :)